# What's the best web testing tool for beginners with no previous automation experience?

Tags: automated-testing, tools

What automation tool for testing web application can you recommend to beginners? Which one is better to start with? I have no automation testing experience.

Comment: Sadia - if you browse through the SQA site, you will find many tool suggestions for test automation.

Comment: It appears my comment yesterday didn't post... strange. Anyway, this might be a serious problem for you, but in its current state it isn't refined enough. It would require an evaluation of the tools available, their pros and cons, and your environment, which is far beyond the scope of a single question on SQA.

Comment: Question is refined. Please re-open it. I can give an answer with new information.

Comment: Selenium IDE is easy-to-use tool with Record-And-Play functionality. So it's one of the best web testing tools for beginners.

Comment: Sorry Dmitry, it's a start but right now the question is just so open ended. There's no way to really compare the different ones. There's just too many factors.

Answer (score 3):

"Most appropriate" is the one that best meets your company's individual needs.

It depends on the technology, but also the budget, the time available, the knowledge and capacity of the individual(s) who will be using the tool, etc, etc. No one size fits all.

Here is a list of vendors that have trial versions you might choose to explore. Not only will this give you some exposure to the tools available, but it will also help you understand which capabilities are important to your individual situation:

http://www.allthingsquality.com/2010/04/trial-versions-of-commercial-test.html

I use WinTask. It meets my needs at this time, but it might or might not meet yours.

Here is what I look for in general terms when I put together a suite of automated test tools. You might find it handy:

http://www.allthingsquality.com/2010/04/things-i-like-to-have-in-my-test.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the technology your web app is based on. For instance you have great Unit Testing in Visual Studio for ASP.NET MVC. In PHP you have PHPUnit, JUnit for Java EE, etc.

Comment: But this tool is for unit testing not for functional testing, any reference can you suggest me for functional testing?